# Dealing with old Thunderbird inbox e-mails in the terminal

Tags: command-line, thunderbird, text-processing

I want to run a loop on all of Thunderbird's inbox e-mail so that I can find and copy some pieces from them to a text file.

How can I do this in a terminal?

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Recover_messages_from_a_corrupt_folder says those are kept in mbox files. You could probably use [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html) to parse them.

Comment: Thanks muru. Yes, it seems to be no way to parse them in bash, I'll try to use python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing [kb.mozillazine.org](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Recover_messages_from_a_corrupt_folder):

> Thunderbird uses mbox files to store the messages for a folder. Each mbox file is an ordinary 7-bit ASCII text file with the folders name and no file extension. You can read the messages using a text editor though it will be very user unfriendly due to all of the headers that are normally hidden, HTML tags not being interpreted, and seeing big blocks of characters all run together for any binary attachments.

If you don't mind some gibberish those files can simply be processed with `grep` and friends, for example:

```
$ grep -r --exclude="*.msf" "Subject: some subject" /path/to/Inbox.sbd
mail_dir_01:Subject: some subject
$ sed -n '/Subject: some subject/,/^From - /p' mail_dir_01
```

Here, `grep` searches all mail folders inside the Inbox for a mail with the subject “some subject” and gives you its folder file name `mail_dir_01`, `sed` then displays the mail from the `Subject:` line on. However, `awk` may provide better approaches.